# Meu formulario de contato esta chegando no email de destino como "undefined"

Tags: php, html, email, envio-de-email, undefined

estava funcionando tudo perfeitamente, porém, quando preencho as informações do formulário e clico em enviar, no e-mail chega assim:

Nome: undefined
Email: undefined
Mensagem: undefined

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor, segue abaixo meu código html e php:

PHP

```
<?php 
$errorMSG = "";

if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Name is required ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Email is required ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Message is required ";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}

if (empty($_POST["terms"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Terms is required ";
} else {
    $terms = $_POST["terms"];
}

$to = "contato@supremotec.com.br";
$subject = "Contato - Supremotec Tecnologia";
$body = "Nome: " . $name . "\n" . "Email: " . $email . "\n" . "Mensagem: " . $message;

// prepare email body text $Body = ""; $Body .= "Name: "; $Body .= $name; $Body .= "\n"; $Body .= "Email: "; $Body .= $email; $Body .= "\n"; $Body .= "Menssagem: "; $Body .= $message; $Body .= "\n";

// send email

$header = "From:comercial@supremotec.com.br" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To:" . $email . "\e\n" . "X=Mailer:PHP/" . phpversion(); {

    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {

        echo ("Email enviado com sucesso!");
    } else {
        echo ("O email não pode ser enviado");
    }
}
?>
```

HTML

```
                <form id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" data-focus="false">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control-input" id="name" required>
                        <label class="label-control" for="name">Nome</label>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control-input" id="email" required>
                        <label class="label-control" for="email">Email</label>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control-textarea" id="message" required></textarea>
                        <label class="label-control" for="message">Sua mensagem</label>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="form-control-submit-button">ENVIAR MENSAGEM</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-message">
                        <div id="cmsgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- end of contact form -->   
            </div> <!-- end of col -->
        </div> <!-- end of row -->
    </div> <!-- end of container -->
</div> <!-- end of form-2 -->
<!-- end of contact -->
```

Obs. Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Comment: Edite a questão e coloque o código php em texto. e se possível, coloque o código do erro completo.

Comment: Me desculpe, não estou conseguindo editar  a questão.

Comment: Enfim, consegui postar o código em php adequadamente na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

**ATUALIZADO**
Encontrei alguns erros no seu formulário.

1. Está faltando o atributo `name` nos inputs do seu formulário hmtl.
2. está faltando o atributo `action` no seu formulário com a rota para o arquivo php
3. Está faltando o atributo `method="post"` no seu formulário.

```html
<form id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" data-focus="false" action="mail.php" method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control-input" id="name" name="name" required>
            <label class="label-control" for="name">Nome</label>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" class="form-control-input" id="email" name="email" required>
            <label class="label-control" for="email">Email</label>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control-textarea" id="message" name="message" required></textarea>
            <label class="label-control" for="message">Sua mensagem</label>
            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="form-control-submit-button">ENVIAR MENSAGEM</button>
        </div>
        <div class="form-message">
            <div id="cmsgSubmit" name="cmsgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: <form id="contactForm" data-toggle="validator" data-focus="false">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="name" class="form-control-input" id="name" name="name" required>
                    <label class="label-control" for="name">Nome</label>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>

Comment: Continua a chegar o os dados do formulario via email como "Undefined*

Comment: editei a resposta, adicionando mais algumas coisas que estão faltando no formulário